# Check if part of string contains regex pattern

Tags: python, string

I have a list of strings.
Each string contains random text and a sequence of numbers and letters that may or may not match a regex.

Example string:

```
"Bla bla bla 123-abc-456 bla bla blaaha"
```

`123-abc-456` will match a regex.

I wish to store all those matching sequences into a new list; sequence only that is, not the bla bla bla.

How could this be done? I need to break out the sequence only using the regex somehow.

Comment: Not possible. Even arbitrary string can be a regex.

Comment: `bla bla bla` is a valid regex

Comment: you have to chose a subset of regexs otherwise the problem is unsolvable

Comment: I think @nhahtdh, jamylak, and gipi are misreading this question.

Comment: @sigmavirus24 what does it mean then? I'm too tired

Comment: They have a regular expression already written, and want to use it on the string. They have done no research on regular expression usage in python or the `re` module. They're not trying to test if there exists a regular expression inside the string which seems to be how you three are reading it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you have only one "sequence" per string that you are interested in:

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: re.search(r'\d{3}-\D{3}-\d{3}',
    ..: "Bla bla bla 123-abc-456 bla bla blaaha").group()
Out[2]: '123-abc-456'
```

Just do this in a `for` loop and save results to a new list.

If you want multiple matches, use `re.findall` as suggested above.

Answer (score 1):

Use braces in your regexp. Then, you can use groups(1), groups(2) to isolate matching parts back.